# Page reloads when input type="number" is changed by buttons

Tags: html, forms, input

To simplify I have a basic HTML structure where inside an  I have one number input and it's respective add and subtracts buttons. Every time one of the buttons it's clicked the page automatically reloads. How do I prevent that from happening?

This is my code:

```html
<form>
  ...
  <button   onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" class="icon-number ver"></button>
<input class="quantity" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
<button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus icon-number ver"></button>
  
  <button class="btn-form btn-add-cart" type="submit">ADD TO CART</button>
  
</form>
```

The issue disappears when I remove the form tag, but I would like to keep it.
I am not using any javascript on this code, it's just HTML.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please, including your JavaScript

Comment: @j08691 I am not using any javascript, the problem it's reproduced when you run the code snippet

Comment: Running your snippet in Chrome on Windows does nothing when changing the number input via the arrows. If you're referring to the *buttons* in the form well then that's the expected behavior as the default type for buttons is submit. Change it to something like button and it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Comment: Thanks @j08691 that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be submitting the form after you click the button.
I tried your code at my local machine and could fix it using attribute type like this.

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus icon-number ver"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your functions are returning false

```html
<form>
  ...
  <button   onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown(); return false;" class="icon-number ver"></button>
<input class="quantity" min="0" max="99" name="quantity" value="1" type="number">
<button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp(); return false;" class="plus icon-number ver"></button>
  
  <button class="btn-form btn-add-cart" type="submit">ADD TO CART</button>
  
</form>
```